# Will there be any impact on the VM which is running after Failover of an on-prem server if the server from the replicated list is disabled & removed?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, failover, azure-site-recovery, azure-vm

The on-premise server which was replicated has been Failover-ed and the VM is successfully running. After that we needed to enable the "Complete Migration" feature but the configuration server developed IOPS issue and this process could not be completed. After the config server was hard-reset, the server now is showing as "Protection couldn't be disabled" and also the "Complete Migration" feature is not enabled.

Now have thought to use the "Disable Replication" feature which will remove the server from the replicated item's list. Just wanted to ask, will it impact the VM which is running in ANY way ? Or can it be done without any issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you disable replication, only replication is removed. However, the failed over VM in Azure will still exist as long as you don't stop/de-allocate the VM.